# C# Sentiment Analysis

Tags: c#, text-mining

Does anyone know of a (preferably open source) C# library that can be implemented to calculate the overall sentiment of some given text?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at an open source sentiment analysis engine based on Naive Bayes classification at https://github.com/amrishdeep/Dragon.

Comment: did  you use it in real world? do you know best getting started - *step by step guide* about it?

Answer (score 2):

http://rapid-i.com/content/view/26/84/

maybe not c# but I guess you can call it from c#, will it does the job for you?

Comment: did  you use it in real world? do you know **best getting started** - *step by step guide* about it?