# Free Library for Sentiment Analysis (on Tweets) in C#

Tags: c#, dll, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I need a simple Sentiment Analysis library to use in my ASP.NET application. The library should be able to work on short strings (Twitter tweets have a maximum length of 140 characters long), and only needs to classify the tweets as positive or negative (and perhaps neutral, but not necessary).

I have found many similar questions on Stack Overflow, but haven't managed to find a class library in C# that quite fits my requirements.

I found this really cool webservice called uClassify that does exactly what I need, thanks to the post at [Algorithm to determine how positive or negative a statement/text is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326171/algorithm-to-determine-how-positive-or-negative-a-statement-text-is).

But I want a library, not a web service. I will be processing thousands of tweets and the overhead of making HttpRequests is too much.

Comment: Perhaps this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494276/c-sharp-sentiment-analysis

Comment: @M.Babcock, thank you for your suggestion, but I had already seen that post. Rapid-Miner is a full-blown software package and seems to be an overkill for what I want. I was wondering if there's a simple class library. Something similar to uClassify would be perfect.

Comment: @Rachel Did you ever have any luck with this? I'm looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: @BrianMacKay No, I had ended up using the uClassify web service.

Comment: @Rachel In that case, may I ask how it went? It looks like it should be pretty easy to use.

Comment: @BrianMacKay: It's been a while, but I remember it was quite easy to use, and the web service was pretty fast. Although sentiment analysis wasn't that accurate on certain tweets...

Comment: did you get final solution?

Comment: No, I used uClassify, as mentioned in previous comment.